# Recommendations for a wireless print server supported on Linux?

Tags: printing

I have found it difficult to research a **wireless print server** which will be supported on Linux.  I use Debian 6 and Ubuntu 10.04 (also Windows 7 64 bit, Vista, and MACOS Snow Leopard).  Everyone in my household using uses a different OS, so it is all the more difficult to ensure interoperability across so many OSs.

Where can I find a definitive, authoritative and complete list of supported print servers?

Also, I want to keep things simple as possible.  This is an important criterion for my choice of wireless print server.  GUI mediated setup/install is much preferred over complex configuration files and command line.  I know of CUPs, but I don't know if CUPs will regulate the wireless print server and what's involved.

The print server is to enable sharing of Brother HL-4050CDN printer.

Edit: I'm seriously considering the [Belkin F5L049au](http://www.belkin.com/au/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=508689).  But the customer support people tell me it does not support Linux.  But this is true of the majority of the print server market...  Anybody, help?

Edit2: Must support N network standard, the printer above, be wireless, and be Linux compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the problem more complicated that it needs to be.  You should only need to investigate using a print server when the printer does not have any networking functionality itself, such as a USB-only or Parallel port device.

Therefore the question becomes: how do you get a non-wireless device onto a wireless network?

There are two solutions:

1. Connect the printer network port directly into your wireless router device.
2. Use a WiFi bridge to extend the wireless signal onto Ethernet, supported by most access point devices and possible with most wireless routers.

http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-basics/30338-how-to-convert-a-wireless-router-into-an-access-point